# Filling missing rows , RIGHT JOIN with each group of GROUP BY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

On one table I have Id, and Name of 10 tests whitch should be done.
On second SN product, TestDate, and Id test that have been done to this product.
I need to find, and show tests whitch should be done but they are not.

Solution with CROSS JOIN, and LEFT OUTER JOIN works for 1000 rows, but for 8000-15000 it takes a long time 1-3 minutes. 
Data are prepared by CTE query

example below
I want to add "missing" row to each group @Table2

```
@Table1 => four tests which should be done 
       number - Id of test
       data3  -name of test
@Table2 => tests which were done
       data1 - id of tested device
GROUP   => tests of one device

DECLARE @table1 TABLE (data3 NVARCHAR(20), number INT)
DECLARE @table2 TABLE (data1 NVARCHAR(20), data2 NVARCHAR(20), number INT)  

INSERT INTO @table1 
    SELECT 'xx', 1 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'ee', 2 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'zz', 3 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'gg', 4

INSERT INTO @table2 
    SELECT '1', 'aaaaaaaaaa', 1 --GROUP 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '1', 'aaaaaaaaaa', 2 --GROUP 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '1', 'aaaaaaaaaa', 3 --GROUP 1
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2', 'bbbbbbbbbb', 1 --GROUP 2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '2', 'bbbbbbbbbb', 2 --GROUP 2
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '3', 'cccccccccc', 1 --GROUP 3
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT '3', 'cccccccccc', 3 --GROUP 3
```

With this query only one row was added (first one), I need to fill each group of table2

If my group is eg. GROUP BY data1,data2

```
SELECT * 
FROM @table2 t2
RIGHT JOIN @table1 t1 ON t2.number = t1.number
ORDER BY t2.data1, t1.number
```

Output:

```
 data1  data2       number  data3   number
 -----------------------------------------
 NULL   NULL        NULL    gg      4
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  1       xx      1
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  2       ee      2
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  3       zz      3
 2      bbbbbbbbbb  1       xx      1
 2      bbbbbbbbbb  2       ee      2
 3      cccccccccc  3       zz      3
 3      cccccccccc  1       xx      1
```

This is my required output (although only one 'number' column would also work)

```
 data1  data2       number  number3
 -----------------------------------------
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  1       1          --GROUP 1
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  2       2          --GROUP 1
 1      aaaaaaaaaa  3       3          --GROUP 1
 NULL   NULL        NULL    4          --GROUP 1
 2      bbbbbbbbbb  1       1          --GROUP 2
 2      bbbbbbbbbb  2       2          --GROUP 2
 NULL   NULL        NULL    3          --GROUP 2
 NULL   NULL        NULL    4          --GROUP 2
 3      cccccccccc  1       1          --GROUP 3
 NULL   NULL        NULL    2          --GROUP 3
 3      cccccccccc  3       3          --GROUP 3
 NULL   NULL        NULL    4          --GROUP 3
```

Comment: I think you have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Can you explain the use case?

Comment: It's great that you posted sample data as DDL+DML, your current attempt and your desired results. However your question text could be clearer. You should think about would you explain the problem to someone that doesn't do SQL, then [edit] your question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why your `data1` are null for *missing* values? I guess they must be filled from table2. Try this query:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        distinct a.data1, b.number, b.data3
    from
        @table2 a
        cross join @table1 b
)

select
    c.data1, t.data2, t.number, c.data3, number3 = c.number
from
    cte c
    left join @table2 t on c.data1 = t.data1 and c.number = t.number
```

Output

```
data1   data2        number   data3   number3
---------------------------------------------
1       aaaaaaaaaa   1        xx      1
1       aaaaaaaaaa   2        ee      2
1       aaaaaaaaaa   3        zz      3
1       NULL         NULL     gg      4
2       bbbbbbbbbb   1        xx      1
2       bbbbbbbbbb   2        ee      2
2       NULL         NULL     zz      3
2       NULL         NULL     gg      4
3       cccccccccc   1        xx      1
3       NULL         NULL     ee      2
3       cccccccccc   3        zz      3
3       NULL         NULL     gg      4
```

If you really need to show null values in data1 column, then add case statement to check value of data2.

Comment: --"Why your data1 are null for missing values?"
'Table1' =>  four tests which should be done
'Table2' => tests which were done

Comment: @Artur, I guess you are talking about columns `number` and `number3`. `Number` - tests which were done, `number3` - tests which should be done. And I believe `data1` which is group number should not be null. But if you really want them to be null just change `c.data1` to `case when t.data2 is null then null else c.data1 end` in the last select.

Comment: Yes, you ar right. 
Query works fine for 1000 rows in table2 but for 15000 rows it takes 60 seconds :(

Comment: On one table I have Id, and Name of 10 tests whitch should be done. On second SN product, TestDate, and Id test that have been done to this product. I need to find, and show tests whitch should be done but they are not.

Comment: I did not understand what you mean. Doesn't this query return your expected result? If your issue is the performance of the query, that's completely another question. You should ask another question providing full table structures. Then you may get some tips on indexing tables